# Spring boot не хочет выводить мои ошибки валидации в Noty

Tags: java, json, spring, валидация, noty

Добавляется equipments, в логах всё отлично, выводится, что в полях ошибки:

```
2023-01-17 09:50:17.882  WARN 12684 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] r.i.util.exception.ExceptionInfoHandler  : VALIDATION_ERROR at request  http://localhost:8081/profile/equipments/: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 5 errors
Field error in object 'equipment' on field 'description': rejected value []; codes [NotBlank.equipment.description,NotBlank.description,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [equipment.description,description]; arguments []; default message [description]]; default message [не должно быть пустым]
Field error in object 'equipment' on field 'company': rejected value []; codes [Size.equipment.company,Size.company,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [equipment.company,company]; arguments []; default message [company],70,2]; default message [размер должен находиться в диапазоне от 2 до 70]
Field error in object 'equipment' on field 'name': rejected value []; codes [NotBlank.equipment.name,NotBlank.name,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [equipment.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [не должно быть пустым]
Field error in object 'equipment' on field 'description': rejected value []; codes [Size.equipment.description,Size.description,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [equipment.description,description]; arguments []; default message [description],120,2]; default message [размер должен находиться в диапазоне от 2 до 120]
Field error in object 'equipment' on field 'name': rejected value []; codes [Size.equipment.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [equipment.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],128,2]; default message [размер должен находиться в диапазоне от 2 до 128]
```

Но у меня есть js, в котором это должно выводиться:

```js
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, options, jsExc) {
        alert(event);
        alert(options);
        failNoty(jqXHR,options);
    });
```

---

```js
function failNoty(jqXHR,options) {

    closeNoty();
    var errorInfo = jqXHR.responseJSON;
    failedNote = new Noty({
        text: ""+errorInfo.typeMessage+"",
        type: "error",
        layout: "bottomRight"
    });
    failedNote.show();
}
```

Вместо ошибок выдаётся undefined.

EquipmentUIController:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(value = EquipmentUIController.URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class EquipmentUIController extends AbstractEquipmentController{
    static final String URL = "/profile/equipments";

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<EquipmentTo> getAll() {
        log.info("EquipmentUIController getAll");
        return  super.getAll() ;
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void createOrUpdate(@Validated(View.Web.class) Equipment equipment) {
        log.info("EquipmentUIController createOrUpdate");
        if (equipment.isNew()) {
            super.create(equipment);
        } else {
            super.update(equipment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Equipment get(@PathVariable int id) {
        log.info("EquipmentUIController get id");
        return super.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        super.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Не знаю какие участки кода вывести сюда, сам проект не маленький, вот git:
https://github.com/Dvorneg/it

Answer (score 0):

Начало выводить ошибку, добавил в свойства spring boot:

```
spring.jackson.visibility.field=any
spring.jackson.visibility.getter=none
spring.jackson.visibility.setter=none
spring.jackson.visibility.is-getter=none
```

без этого ошибка не формировалась

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).